# Trying to use the effectStart and effectEnd from a LIST object in Flex 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, list, events, effect

I have a mobile app that populates a list.  This takes a couple of seconds so I am trying to display the busyindicator.  I display the busy indicator when the view is activated and then when the list is complete I want to turn off the busy indicator.

My MXML for the busy indicator and the list declaration is like so:

```
<s:BusyIndicator id="BI"  visible="true" />

<s:List id="lst"  effectStart="lstStartHandler(event)"  effectEnd="lstFinishHandler(event)" fontSize="20" horizontalCenter="0" textAlign="right"  dataProvider="{dp}" useVirtualLayout="true" width="100%" height="100%" top="30" alternatingItemColors="[#66FFFF, #33CCCC]">
```

My event listeners are like so:

```
private function lstFinishHandler(event:EffectEvent):void {
            BI.visible = false
        }

        private function lstStartHandler(event:EffectEvent):void {
            BI.visible = true
        }
```

My busy indicator always stays on and never goes invisible.  It appears the event functions do not execute.

Obviously I am doing something wrong but cannot figure it out.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `effectStart` and `effectEnd` properties in MXML are to add event handlers when a Flex effect class is playing an effect on your component.

If you are not triggering any effects on the `List`, then those event handlers are not going to be executed.

You need to tell the busy indicator to go away by some other means:

- dispatch your own event
- use data binding
- use view states and the currentState property
- etc...

You are already using data binding to set the `dataProvider` for the list, you could simply add another variable and bind to the visible property of the `BusyIndicator`:

```
<s:BusyIndicator visible="{isServerResponseComplete}" />
```

It feels **wrong** to add a bindable variable (`isServerResponseComplete') just to do this, but it's the simplest answer. Dispatching an event is probably a better approach, but it's difficult to say exactly how you should do it w/out knowing how your app is structured.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I created my own event (your 1st option) and determined that the List control was actually created very quickly with no delay so that ended up a dead end. But I realised that it was the itemRenderer for the list that was causing the delay. I therefore used the updateComplete event of the itemRenderer and that worked to hide the busyindicator after the itemRenderer completed.

thanks for your input.